# Send data and Change Page on button press using UIPageControl

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, uipagecontrol

I am using `UIPageControl` and `UIScrollView` to move between the views by scrolling.

I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168).

I have a button in the first of the view controllers. 
I would like to send data to the second view controller and also change the page. I would like to know how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have all of the view controllers created (born at least the first 2) rather than loading purely on demand (scroll).

Add a property to the first controller which holds a reference to the second controller. Set the reference when the instances are created.

When the button is tapped, use the reference to call a method on the second controller.

Comment: But I need to pass the data obtained from the first view controller to the second one

Comment: Yeah, your only problem is getting a reference to the second controller so you can call a method to pass the data. Did you try?

Comment: I would also like to know how to change the view on pressing the button.

Comment: I could change the view by calling the parent view controller from the child as mentioned in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195283/uipagecontrol-change-page-on-click-of-button/21196288?noredirect=1#comment31918513_21196288