# UIPageControl - Change page on click of button

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uipagecontrol

I am using `UIPageControl` along with `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to switch between view controllers. The pages are changed using swipe.

I also need to change the page when a `UIButton` is pressed on one of the view controllers.

Here is how the swipe is used to change the views:

```
- (void)swipeRightToLeftGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (self.pageControl.currentPage == 0) { 
       [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                 animations:^{

                     for (UIViewController *vc in self.childViewControllers) {
                         CGRect frame = vc.view.frame;
                         frame.origin.x -= self.view.frame.size.height;
                         vc.view.frame = frame;
                 }
      }];
      self.pageControl.currentPage = 1;
   }
}
```

I hope the question is clear. I tried my best to make it clear.

Comment: When you say "navigate" do you mean with a `UINavigationController` or a `UIScrollView` or something else? Please be a little more specific.

Comment: I made an edit to the post.

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little cheeky, really you should refactor the method, but:

Assuming you are on page zero (I guess there is a different button on page 1), then you can just call your method and pass `nil` as the parameter. The gesture isn't actually used so everything should be fine.

Comment: Should I call the changePage method? If so, how can I call it from a child view controller?

Comment: Call the `swipeRightToLeftGesture` method. From a child VC you can use `self.parentViewController` and a cast to call the method.

Comment: Could you please let me know the code. I am getting an error on using `[self.parentViewController swipeRightToLeftGesture];` .  `

Comment: Cast and parameter. 
   
`[(YourVC)(self.parentViewController) swipeRightToLeftGesture :nil];` hopefully I got the brackets right...

Comment: I am having another issue now. The new view is not being reloaded. On pressing the button, the second view should change based on a parameter. But it is as it is when it is loaded. Any ideas why?

Comment: How are you asking it to reload? You should really create a new question.

Comment: I posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223143/uipagecontrol-reload-page-on-click-of-button