# UIPageControl - reload page on click of button

Tags: ios, uibutton, uipagecontrol, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am using `UIPageControl` and `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to switch between pages.

This is an extension to this question [UIPageControl - Change page on click of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195283/uipagecontrol-change-page-on-click-of-button)

The solution provided in the above mentioned thread enables me to change the page. In my application, the next page needs to be reloaded based on a parameter that is passed when the button is pressed. I am able to pass the parameter and I see it in when I do `NSLog` in the next view controller. But I am unable to understand why the page is not being reloaded.

Edit:
The second view consists of a plot which loads based on the parameter I pass. Currently, only the initial plot is seen even on switching to the next page and passing the parameter.

The parameter sets a global static variable of the second view controller in a function. The plot is created based on this parameter in the `viewDidAppear` method of the second view controller.

Comment: Show the code for the parameter being set. What should be updating the UI but isn't? What does it do instead (nothing)?

Comment: @Wain: I used the method suggested by you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125939/send-data-and-change-page-on-button-press-using-uipagecontrol for passing the parameter.

Comment: That gives you a reference so you can call. But you need to make a call (you say you are) - what does that code do? Show it. You need to redraw. viewDidAppear isn't called again if you don't call it because you are just animating view positions...

Comment: Thanks! I called viewDidAppear now in the swipeGesture recognizer and it works! So we need to call them manually I guess when we use UIPageControl and UISwipeGetureRescongizer!

Comment: @Wain: Maybe you could explain this in detail as an answer as to exactly how this combination of page control and swipe gesture works - and when the viewDidAppear be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidAppear` is only called when you call it if your view controller is a container. It's your responsibility to call this (and associated) methods as you show and hide the child view controllers views.

Basically, when you swipe and animate you should call the will show and hide methods on the 2 controllers just before and the did show and hide methods on both controllers in the animation completion block.